# The color is shown wrongly in the Excel after configuring 3 rules in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a excel file with 3 sheets. I would like to perform highlighting the cells if the cell is not available in another sheets. Let me show you the link below on how does my sheets look like and give you more explanation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YwOL.png)

Based on that link, if the cell from the Student sheet is not available in Subject and Sport, the highlight will be yellow. If the cell from the Student sheet is in Subject  the highlight will be red. If the cell from the Student sheet is in Sport  it will be green. Otherwise, it will be white. I implemented 3 rules in the conditional formatting.

The first rule is to match cell from the Student to the Subject. Then it will be highlighted red. The code is down below.

```
=MATCH(A2,Sport!B:B,0)>0
```

The second rule is to match cell from the Student to the Sport. Then it will be highlighted green. the code is down below.

```
=MATCH(A2,Subject!B:B,0)>0
```

Lastly the rule is to highlight the cells if the cell is not available in both sheets, Sport and Subject. It will be highlighted yellow. the code is down below.

```
=AND(MATCH(A2,Subject!$B:$B,0)=0,MATCH(A2,Sport!$B:$B,0)=0)
```

However, the result is not what I expected. It is different from the first link. There is no yellow being highlighted.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNe2K.png)

Can you please give me advice or correct this problem? Thank you.

Comment: If MATCH is unsuccessful in finding a match, it returns the #N/A error value.  Not Zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding IFERROR to return true or false.

```
=AND(IFERROR(MATCH(A2,Subject!$B:$B,0),0)=0,IFERROR(MATCH(A2,Sport!$B:$B,0),0)=0)
```